# Touch and Canvas element location do not match

Tags: c#, unity3d-2dtools

I'm trying to create a game like [WordCookie](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rOolPY5L1fA). I want to use a LineRenderer, so I cannot use the `Screen Space - Overlay` Canvas Renderer mode. When using either `Screen Space - Camera` or `World View`, my `Touch` position doesn't match the position I get from my `RectTransforms`.

I access my buttons' transform position by logging:

```
foreach (RectTransform child in buttons.transform)
{
    Debug.Log("assigning" + child.transform);
}
```

For the touch cooridinates, I simply log the `touch.position`.

To clarify; I want to trigger my LineRenderrer when the distance between the position vectors is smaller than a certain float. However, whenever I tap on my button to test this, the button logs at (1.2, -2.6) and my touch at (212.2, 250.4).

What could be causing this?

Answer (score 0):

`touch.position` returns a value using **pixel coordinates**.
In order to convert to **world coordinates** you need to use: [Camera.ScreenToWorldPoint](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera.ScreenToWorldPoint.html) 
Should be something like that:

```
Vector2 touch = Input.GetTouch(0);
float buttonPositionZ = button.transform.position.z;

Vector3 worldPosition = camera.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(touch.x, touch.y, buttonPositionZ));
```